# Move Excel Window behind windows form

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I am trying to program a windows form which opens and edits an Excel file adding in the current date and time. I want to be able to see the change when it happens on the file and keep the file open. This is accomplished by the current code.

```
 public void appendDate(string filePath, int row, int col)
        {
            Excel.Application excel = null;
            excel = new Excel.Application();

            excel.Visible = true;
            //excel.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal;
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Excel.Workbook wkb = null;

            wkb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath, ReadOnly: false);
            excel.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal;
            var ws = wkb.Worksheets[1];
            DateTime dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
            ws.Cells[row, col].Value = dateAndTime;

            wkb.Save();
        }
```

I call this method when a certain button is clicked on the windows form. My issue is that other events take place after the excel file is edited during the same button click. After this method is called, I want the excel file to be minimized or I would like it to be possible for the user to click on the windows form UI and move it to the front. Right now, the excel file is blocking windows form until the program tasks on the button click have been completed.

I tried to minimize the window before the open command in the program:

`excel.WindowState = Excel.XlWindowState.xlNormal;`

However, when I opened the minimized window after the program finished executing, the change wasn't visible in the actual cell and only showed the correct text in the formula line in excel.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to hide the Excel file, you could try calling [`Activate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activate?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) on the Windows Form to bring it back to the front, after the operations within the Excel file have been made.